# Why i can not to check my ftp connection in wso2

Tags: ftp, wso2

I have a proxy service in wso2. This service uses the ftp settings with which I download files. But sometimes it doesn't work as I expect it to. How can I check the ftp connection in wso2 and, if I get a timeout or connection refused, make a reconnection?

It is parameters of my proxy service in wso2

````
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain;charset=UTF-8</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:ftp://login:password@host/outgoing</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">DELETE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:ftp://login:password@host/outgoing/error</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.csv</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following parameter.

```
transport.vfs.MaxRetryCount
```

Comment: But this parameter defaults to three, and it doesn't work in my case. My proxy just did not see the file and did not respond despite the fact that the file was in the folder on the ftp server side and before that my proxy worked fine. In this case restarting the service helped and I want to foresee this case in my service in the future.